# Getting rid of old scala version and install 2.11.7

Tags: scala, ubuntu

Noob question incoming.

I just uninstalled `scala 2.9.2` from my machine in doing:

```
sudo apt-get remove scala
```

While the command:

```
scala -version
```

outputs:

```
The program 'scala' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: sudo apt-get install scala
```

My `scala`/`sbt` program still functions...

Why? I do not know.

I would like to install the latest version of `scala` which is the `2.11.7`.

My questions are:
- How do I fully uninstall `scala`?
- How do I install `scala 2.11.7`? (In which directory uncompress the `.tgz`? What bindings?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. SBT is not scala
2. the command sbt usually is a wrapper script that launches `sbt-launch.jar` in *[home]/.sbt/launchers*. Where that wrapper script is installed to heavily depends on how you installed it.
3. SBT downloads its own scala version into a projects `target` path. It is totally local, so imo there is not reason to worry about installation relics.
4. Thus, if you want to use scala 2.11.7, just set `scalaVersion := 2.11.7` in your build.sbt